# Swift 3 - for loop

Tags: for-loop, swift3

I'm not sure what the (0 + 1) does to the loop.

```
for i in ((0 + 1)...n).reversed() {
    if n % i != 0 { 
        continue 
    }
```

Comment: Unsurprisingly, `0+1` is just `1`. It's the same as `for i in (1...n).reversed() { ... }`. We can only guess as to the author's intent, why he/she did `0+1` rather than just `1`. Perhaps you can share a link/reference to where you got that code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.